# Cucumber: How to access steps from features in subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm currently writing up some cucumber specs, and I'm trying to keep features organised by module. So, for example, my admin/posts controller is stored in features/admin/posts

The difficulty is whenever I run the feature from that directory it doesn't recognise any of the steps in features/step_definitions.

In short, how do I include all base step_definitions in my feature subdirectories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're actually in that folder, then you would need to tell cucumber to `require` the step  definitions on the command line e.g.

```
myproject/features/admin/posts$ cucumber . -r ../../features/step_definitions
```

It's a bit messy as you would also have to include the location of any support files, if you use them:

```
myproject/features/admin/posts$ cucumber . -r ../../features/step_definitions -r ../../features/support
```

A slightly easier way would be to always run cucumber from your root directory, and specify which features you want to be run, and just `require` the whole features folder:

```
myproject$ cucumber -r features features/admin/posts
```

Would run all the features in the admin/posts directory, and also pull in the necessary step definitions and support files.

Comment: Also see here for a neat idea to make it simpler: http://lmarburger.github.com/2009/09/cucumber-features-in-subdirectories.html

Comment: Many thanks. (In case anyone else has a similar issue: remember to reset spork/guard!)